# Custom multiselct product attribute not showing selected in admin

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I have created a custom multiselct product attribute pro grammatically. Everything is working fine i.e values are
saving in databases and values also showing in product grid.But the selected values is not showing selected while editing the product.[image]

However If I create multiselct attribute from admin it showing selected .

[image]

Comment: Please try after indexing and save it again.

Comment: I did re-indexing many times, but still the issue exist.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have solved it by following steps:

**Step 1:** Goto **'eav_attribute'** table directly into the database and find the attribute code.

**Step 2:** Then check the `'backend_type'`. It should be **'varchar'** if not then change it to **varchar** manually.

**Step 3:** Now check `'backend_model'`. It should be `'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend'`.

After the above changes flush the cache and test again.

Comment: I have already did this after lot of investigation. But it din't work.
Attached the image of DB above.

Comment: Can you replace varchar by text and test again? Also did you flush the cache and reindex?

Comment: No , replacing varchar by text also not work

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was mentioned here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5885

Here is the patch for 2.1.x
https://gist.github.com/tuyennn/77c3308b54b9abb7a907429c50166b6d

Or you could follow the merge commit and internal MAGETWO-57153 to trace and fix the issue